# Is abalone still a draw when played with more than 14 marbles per player?

Tags: abalone

After reading the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abalone_(board_game)) for abalone, I realized that the regular abalone is solved as a forced draw.

This led me to question, does there exist an arrangement **with more marbles and/or a larger board** in which the outcome of the game is a win for either side, given perfect play from both sides?